# Synchronizing Clients with Gmail

Tags: gmail-api

What is Synchronizing client with gmail ? Can anybody give a detailed explanation, because i want to have a better understanding over this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if your client keeps any local cache of the Gmail mailbox data like the Message.Id and labels, or headers, or the entire email.  Then in order to update your client you're synchronizing it with Gmail--pulling new updates down to your client.  In cases of clients designed for offline use, then synchronizing may also mean pushing local updates back up to the server (e.g. label updates made by client while "offline" that get applied at some later point).  That's the general definition of synchronizing.

For the Gmail API specific case, Gmail has a backend mailbox-wide history Id.  Any change that affects that account in any way gets a history identifier and most (but not all) history changes affect the state of email messages.  Like adding a new message, changing the labels on a message, or deleting a message.  Clients of the Gmail API can poll the history Id and find out what's changed since the last time they synchronized and pull down updates to maintain their sync.